# Recursive tree traversal with mysql through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, loops, recursion, traversal

I am creating a questionnaire for a client that requires the questions to be organized by 3 layers of levels. I've successfully created the U.I. however I've been trying for the last 3 hours to pull data from a database in such a way that everything loads in the right place. The database is organized like so by the client so I have no control over it:

```
id    description    parentId    
1      Level 1        0           
2      Level 2        0           
3      Level 1a       1   
4      Level 1b       1 
5      Level 1a1      3
```

I have found a similar question to mine on the site but when I attempted it's solution I got the following on repeat infinetly:

Code:

```
function makeList($par_id = 0) {
    //your sql code here
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pB_test WHERE parentId = $par_id");
    $pages = mysql_fetch_array( $result );

    if (count($pages)) {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            echo '<li>', $page['description'];
                makeList($page['parentId']);
                echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
}

makeList();
```

Output:

```
1
3
5
5
l
l
3
5
5
l
l
3
5
5
l
l
3
5
5
l
l
```

Does anyone know how to fix this and what the issue is exactly? Cheers

Comment: MySQL does not support recursive `JOIN`s, which is what you really need, however if you know you only have three levels and will only ever have three levels, you can just left join the table onto itself three times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do this recursivly:

```
function printChildQuestions($parentid) {
  $sql="SELECT * FROM pB_test WHERE parentID=$parentid";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  $i=0;
  while (true) {
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (!$row) break;
    if ($i==0) echo "<ul>";
    $i=1;
    echo '<li>'.$row['id'].'&nbsp;'.$row['description'].'&nbsp;'.$row['parentId'].'</li>';
    printChildQuestions($row['id']);
  }
  if ($i>0) echo '</ul>';
}

printChildQuestions(0);
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! You win the internets today mate!

Comment: Ok, how would I then organize the data into divs so say level1 was a container for all of it's children and there was another div container within that. Then level2 was the next container down the list for that?

Comment: You gotta ask a seperate question: I am a PHP/SQL guy, not a HTML guy, sorry for that

Comment: Well it should still be applicable right? How do I split it up so each level can nest it's own html markup? If you can't do it that's alright. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Basically start from my code: Where I echo `<ul>` you should echo your starting HTML, `</ul>` becomes your ending HTML. The line `<li> ... </li>` is your question. So I suspect it should be something like starting `<div class="..">`, ending `</div>` and your formatted question in the middle.

Comment: K, I'll give it a shot. Cheers mate!

Comment: I dont' understand when $i value became > 0

Comment: bad answer, too many queries to DB, `while (true) { $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (!$row) break;` instead of simply `while($row=mysql_fetch_array)` stupid variable `$i`, etc.

Comment: $i and the if statements using it can be deleted without affecting the result.

Comment: @DanAllen Good catch, thanks! I initially forgot the line `$i=1`. The construction around `$i` is ment to make sure, an **empty** submenu doesn' give an empty `<ul></ul>`.

Answer (score 8):

it's not good to call mysql server and fetch result each time

what if you have over 100 rows? or 200+

use this to query only once:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
$arrs = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $arrs[] = $row;
}

function build_tree($arrs, $parent_id=0, $level=0) {
    foreach ($arrs as $arr) {
        if ($arr['parent_id'] == $parent_id) {
            echo str_repeat("-", $level)." ".$arr['name']."<br />";
            build_tree($arrs, $arr['id'], $level+1);
        }
    }
}

build_tree($arrs);
```

common example for table

```
  id    name    parent_id
```

Comment: You can put `global $arrs;` (instead of passing it as a parameter) inside the function. It wont be a black box any more but you will use much less memory. Also use mysqli instead of mysql.
Anyway I like it.

Comment: This will always fetch the complete table, potentially using Terabytes of RAM - no possibility to fetch a subtree,

Comment: @EugenRieck, just add `WHERE parent_id=$parent_id` clause to your query and 2nd param to `build_tree($arrs, $parent_id)` call. It's obvious that it's not suitable for big data, but will you wrap **terabytes** of results in `<ul><li>` as OP wants?

Comment: Exactly. I would never wrap terabytes into `<ul><li>`, but I would put terabytes into a DB. This broken code will always fetch all rows, so the answer to `what if you have over 100 rows? or 200+` is easy: Definitly not this, as it will break horribly on any sizeable tree.

Comment: @EugenRieck, I meant 100+ **li**st is possible (say in science document) and this will cause 100+ mysql queries each time, which is much worse then 100 times bigger php array

Comment: @EugenRieck, oh, come on, 3-level menu with 100 entries will cause 1000000 **small queries**. learn math

Comment: Thanks @vladkras, by far this is the best solution I've found